# Dockerコンテナ内のプロセス実行時間の計測方法

Tags: docker

Dockerでコンテナを実行し、そのプロセスの実行時間を計測したいと考えています。(このプロセスはdocker createに渡すcmdのパラメータの事です。)
初めは、docker inspectのFinishedAtとStartedAtの差分で計算していましたが、コンテナの起動にかかる時間が余分にかかっているようで望み通りの正確な時間が得られませんでした。
コンテナ内でtimeコマンドなどを動かしたくはありません。
cgroup parentなどを設定してどうにかできるのではないかと模索していますが良い案が思いつきません。

何か方法はありますでしょうか?